# How do I rename a directory via the command line?

Tags: command-line, rename

I have got the directory `/home/user/oldname` and I want to rename it to `/home/user/newname`. How can I do this in a terminal?

Comment: See also: [How to move a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868198/how-to-move-a-directory)

Comment: Use always `mv` or `rename`.

Comment: use `mv` and don't use `/` in end.  Because your content will go inside it.

Answer (score 1037, accepted):

```
mv /home/user/oldname /home/user/newname
```

Comment: Related http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/20667.aspx

Comment: Cool article. That's exactly the point.

Comment: This will not work if the new name is already an existing directory. Instead, it will move the old directory inside the new one.

Comment: If the directory name is the same with capitalization you will get `No such file or directory`. To avoid this do something like `mv /home/user/Folder /home/user/temp; mv /home/user/temp/ /home/user/folder`.

Comment: @cxrodgers: [pass `--no-target-directory` (`-T`)](http://askubuntu.com/a/763915/3712), to avoid treating `newname` as a target directory.

Comment: @jfs: I've been wondering what that option meant for a long time, as the `--help` description isn't particularly useful. Glad to finally know.

Comment: It doesn't work if you want to capitalize a folder on a case-insensitive filesystem (likely on MacOS).
`mv $PWD/analisys $PWD/Analisys` results in `mv: cannot move '/Users/sixtykeys/Projects/murphy/tmp/analisys' to a subdirectory of itself, '/Users/sixtykeys/Projects/murphy/tmp/Analisys/analisys'`

Comment: The “_target directory_” on the man page means “_the directory into which files will be copied_.” As @jfs said, you don’t want to copy _into_ a directory in this case; always use `--no-target-directory` for safety.

Comment: Is there any special reason you used full (absolute) pathnames?

Comment: You can use `mv /home/user/oldname/* /home/user/newname` if `newname` already exists. This will move the contents of `oldname` into the already created `newname` directory.

Answer (score 160):

`mv` can do two jobs.

1. It can move files or directories
2. It can rename files or directories

To just rename a file or directory type this in Terminal:

```
mv old_name new_name
```

with space between the old and new names.

To move a file or directory type this in Terminal.

```
mv file_name ~/Desktop
```

it will move the file to the desktop.

Answer (score 58):

```
mv -T /home/user/oldname /home/user/newname
```

That will rename the directory if the destination doesn't exist or if it exists but it's empty. Otherwise it will give you an error.

If you do this instead:

```
mv /home/user/oldname /home/user/newname
```

One of two things will happen:

- If `/home/user/newname` doesn't exist, it will rename `/home/user/oldname` to `/home/user/newname`
- If `/home/user/newname` exists, it will move `/home/user/oldname` into `/home/user/newname`, i.e. `/home/user/newname/oldname`

Source: [How to decide that mv moves into a directory rather than replacing directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61402/14436)

Comment: Doesn't work if you want to capitalize the directory name in a case-insensitive filesystem (likely on MacOS). `mv -T $PWD/analisys $PWD/Analisys` returns `mv: '/Users/sixtykeys/Projects/murphy/tmp/analisys' and '/Users/sixtykeys/Projects/murphy/tmp/Analisys' are the same file`.
I worked around this by using an intermediate name (i.e. `analisys_`).

Comment: The command may not have been successful due to the limitations of the filesystem, but from another perspective it was successful in interpreting your intentions (renaming a directory, not moving it) :)

Comment: did you try this?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to rename a directory at your level in the file system (e.g., you are at your home directory and want to rename a directory that is also in your home directory):

```
mv Directory ./NewNameDirectory
```

Answer (score 6):

This `gvfs-move` command will also rename files and  directories.

```
gvfs-move /home/user/oldname /home/user/newname
```

Answer (score 5):

gvfs-rename will rename directories as well. It will give an error if a directory with the new name already exists. The only limitation is that you can't use a path with the folder name. So

```
gvfs-rename /home/boo /home/boo-the-dog
```

will not work, but

```
cd /home 
gvfs-rename boo boo-the-dog
```

will work. Not as useful as mv -T but I read in the man that it was meant for network operations.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is using: vidir because I love vi

Install moreutils

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install moreutils
```

Call command vidir in your home-directory

```
vidir ~
```

Now search for the directory to change, using slash / e.g. **/oldname**
make the changes, then press =
ESC
type **:wq**

Done!