# How to rename folders in terminal?

Tags: directory, debian, rename

I need to change `baseoa` to `quake3`. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56326/how-do-i-rename-a-directory-via-the-command-line) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I downvoted this post because there was an exact duplicate elsewhere on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56326/how-do-i-rename-a-directory-via-the-command-line) which was highly upvoted and was very simple to find. Next time make sure you search around before you post your question because most likely someone has had that exact same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use mv to rename `mv old_name new_name`

Comment: Will it work if the folder contains files?